# How to change the color of a surrounding environment as if it were night?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

[image: I want to change the color of the surrounding environment like we are at night]

I want to change the color of the surrounding environment like we are at night

Comment: What do you mean "like we are at night"? Just darker? Can you [edit] the question to add more details?

Comment: You might look into use of LUTs - you can shift tonality and hue and contrast quickly that way. That said, this question needs some more refinement I think.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you don't need a lot to get there - a hue-saturation-lightness adjustment and a curves adjustment should do it pretty quickly.

I masked the laptop screen image mostly, and the popup in front, but left the hand impacted by the blue-shifting and lower lightlevel and higher contrast one typically finds in night scenes - and got to this pretty quickly.

[image]

---

Edit per request in comments!

---

The overall concept is pretty simple - the major tonal elements which make a "night toned" image are fourfold:

1. Desaturation of colours overall
2. Blue shifting of remaining colours
3. Increased contrast
4. Darker overall midpoints

The HSL layer is both aggressively shifting all tones towards cyan / light blue and desaturating all tones; the curves adjustment layer then crushes both lights and darks and further deepens the blue-shift.

The masking of these adjustments means that the tone shifts do not affect the popup UI window, the main display on the screen, and partially affect some of the screen bezel near the graphic and partially affect the near knuckles of the hand, and very slightly affect the far knuckles - that's to imitate the casting of the screen's light and tone on that hand in comparison to the ambient (blueshifted) night scene lighting.

*Here's just the HSL shifting towards the cyan / light blue:*

[image]

*Curves adjustment taking us the rest of the way:*

[image]

*Which gets us here:*

[image]

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nice! Can you explain a bit more which layer does what? I can see this being useful for other viewers.